# How the getsentry log exceptions

Tags: sentry

I am new to Sentry service, I am wondering if Sentry will catch all the exceptions?

Will it log the catched exceptions?

throw "bbbb"

Comment: What do you mean by "bbbb"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass caught exceptions to Sentry, here's an [example in python](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/python/usage/). Sentry also has dozens of clients that integrate with [language frameworks](https://getsentry.com/platforms/) to automatically capture exceptions.